# Partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^{2}+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Concerning the fraction decomposition of $$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^{2}+1)}$$ I get stuck whenever I try to find $A$ and $B$ such that $$\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x^{2}+1}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^{2}+1)}$$

I managed to find $A$ by setting $x=-1$, but finding B gets a bit more complicated. Is there an "elegant" way to find it, or should I do it the hard way and compute this : $$\frac{(x^{2}+1)}{2}+B(x+1)=1$$

(A equals to $\frac{1}{2}$)

Comment: You should use $\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^{2}+1}$

Comment: @Muralidharan What's the reasoning behind this tip?

Comment: @John Mayne The roots of $x^2 +1$ are complex. Thats why you have to use $Bx+ C$.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit Could you link some pertinent material to this constraint? I'm interested in reading about it.

Comment: @JohnMayne If the denominator is a polynomial of degree $n$, the numerator must be a polynomial of degree $n-1$. You can see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup is wrong, since it should be

$$\frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$$

This is because if you have some rational function $$\frac{P(x)}{Q_1(x)Q_2(x)\cdots Q_n(x)}$$

where $Q_i$ are polynomials and the degree of $P$ is less than the total degree of the denominator, you can split this into

$$\frac{P_1(x)}{Q_1(x)} + \frac{P_2(x)}{Q_2(x)} + \cdots + \frac{P_n(x)}{Q_n(x)}$$

where **every $P_i$ is a polynomial of degree one less than $Q_i$**.

---

Given that you know about fraction decomposition, you probably missed that part. If you are covering this at some lecture, the lecturer probably mentioned it and it is somewhere in your notes!

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i)$$
So 
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+i)(x-i)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x+i}+\frac{C}{x-i}$$
Do it similar to what you did for $A$ to find $B$ and $C$.

After that, you can sum the two last terms and write it in a unified term $$\frac{B(x-i)+C(x+i)}{x^2+1}=\frac{(B+C)x+i(B-C)}{x^2+1}$$
If the fraction is real, then $B=C^*$. That is they are complex-conjugate of each other.

Based on this justification, from the beginning you could write the last term as $$\frac{Dx+E}{x^2+1}$$ Obviously, $D=B+C$ and $E=B-C$ in this case and they can be calculated from $$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{Dx+E}{x^2+1}=\frac{A(x^2+1)+(Dx+E)(x+1)}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}\\=\frac{(A+D)x^2+(D+E)x+(A+E)}{(x+1)(x^2+1)}$$
which means
$$D=-A\\E=-D=A\\A+E=1\Rightarrow 2A=1$$